# "The name 'XXX' does not exist in the current context" copying from old file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I copied some code out of an old program and into a new one, it WAS working but now ALL of my objects have this error:

```
The name 'XXX' does not exist in the current context
```

I'm sure it has something to do with the  behind the code file losing a link with the html but all the filenames and references I see match up. Is there something in particular I should check? Thanks in advance!

from html file

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="garrettPenfieldUnit4.Default" %>
```

from .cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace garrettPenfieldUnit4
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        //Load events, automatically inserts todays date and selects the single king radio button
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            arrivalDateBox.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
            singleKingButton.Checked = true;
        }

        //When submit button is clicked show the two confirmation labels.
        protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            submitLabel1.Visible = true;
            submitLabel2.Visible = true;
        }

        //When the clear button is clicked clear the form and reset fields to their default values
        protected void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            arrivalDateBox.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
            departureDateBox.Text = String.Empty;
            peopleDropDown.SelectedIndex = 0;
            singleKingButton.Checked = true;
            twoQueensButton.Checked = false;
            singleQueenButton.Checked = false;
            specialRequestsBox.Text = String.Empty;
            firstNameBox.Text = String.Empty;
            lastNameBox.Text = String.Empty;
            addressBox.Text = String.Empty;
            telephoneNumberBox.Text = String.Empty;
            contactDropDown.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a Web Application Project? Or a website project? Do you have .designer.aspx.cs files?

Comment: I would call it a website. there is no designer file that I know of.

Comment: Well, that's your problem then. You've got a mismatch. Web Application Projects use a designer file to declare controls for the C# types, whereas Website Projects do that behind the scenes. The `CodeBehind` Attribute in your page directive is specifically for Web Application Projects. If you've got no designer files, that's a problem. Use `CodeFile` instead of `CodeBehind` and `ClassName` instead of `Inherits` in a Website Project.

Comment: As it turns out there was a designer file and I needed to copy the code for that as well. I'm still baffled as to how I had it working initially, but thank you for leading me down the correct path!